# How to get multiple images from Pouch

Tags: javascript, image, promise, pouchdb

I have an images table that I need to get multiple sets of images from. I can't figure out an easy way to do this.  I would need to loop through the .get promise call for each image (or set of images).

The following code will get me one image record (which could actually have multiple images in it).

The following code has an array where each cell of the array has a string with an ID and list of attachments (separated by a comma - hence the split) that have been added to this image set.  The s[0] is the image ID and is what gets sent to the ".get" to get the image record which I return and separate each image to use else where.

I can't really chain it as I don't know how many calls I will need to make and putting the calls in a loop is obviously not the way to go.

Is there some way to use these ID's in a Promise.all or Promise.foreach to do this?

In the example, I am returning a promise or a null (been told I should do a Promise.resolve(null)). The sample starts in a ".then" from another pouch call.

```
    if (insertedImages != "") {
       s = insertedImages[0].split(",");
       return DB_TaskImages.get(s[0], { attachments: true });
    }
    else {
       return;
    }
 }).then(function (doc) {
    if (doc != null) {

       iTemp = 0;
```

Thanks.

Here is section of code I am working with

```
     var insertedImages = [];

     DB_WorkIssues.allDocs({ include_docs: true, descending: false }).then(function (response) {

        data = response.rows;
        imageKtr = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < response.total_rows; i++) {
           if (data[i].doc.IsAttachmentInserted) {
              DirtyFlag = true;
              if (data[i].doc.IsAttachmentInserted) {
                 insertedImages[imageKtr++] = data[i].doc._id + "," + data[i].doc.IsAttachmentInserted;
              }
              updated[iTemp++] = data[i];
           }
        }

        if (updated.length > 0) {
           CTL_HiddenJsonWorkIssues.val(JSON.stringify(updated));
        }

        // Handle images - only handling the 1st image record here

        if (insertedImages != "") {
           s = insertedImages[0].split(",");
           return DB_TaskImages.get(s[0], { attachments: true });
        }
        else {
           return;
        }
     }).then(function (doc) {
        if (doc != null) {

           iTemp = 0;

           for (var key in doc._attachments) {
              if (iTemp > 0) {
                 attachments[iTemp] = new Array();
              }
              attachments[iTemp][0] = key;
              attachments[iTemp++][1] = doc._attachments[key];
           }
        }
        if (iTemp > 0) {
           if (attachments[0].length > 0) {
              CTL_HiddenJsonImages.val(JSON.stringify(attachments));
           }
        }
     }).then(function () {
```

This handles a single image fine, but I need it to handle multiples, where the code that gets the image would be changed to do something like the following where the .get would pass a doc (attachment record) to the thenable that follows:

```
        // insertedImages would be an array of something like: "819218,fighterjet.jpg, lions.jpg" 
        // where 819218 is the key for the image record and then a list of images.

        var s;

        if (insertedImages != "") {
           for (var i = 0; i < insertedImages.length;i++) {
              s = insertedImages[i].split(",");
              return DB_TaskImages.get(s[0], { attachments: true });
           }
        }
```

I was thinking of maybe doing something where I would move all the "s[0]" into an array and somehow use that with a Promise.all where the thenable would then be part of the .all function.  Just not sure how to do that.

Comment: `The sample starts in a ".then" from another pouch call.` if that's the case you don't need to `return Promies.resolve(null)` as `.then` always returns a promise, either of the returned value, or, if the returned value is thenable, it "takes on" the value of the thenable

Comment: `putting the calls in a loop is obviously not the way to go` - actually it is the way to go ... set up  `x = Promise.resolve()` - and then each iteration of the loop sets `x = x.then(() => something that returns a promise` ... the chain can be of any arbitrary length

Comment: So you are saying I either return the DB_TaskImages.get() or nothing? So I should just take out the else/return?  I thought you always had to return something.

Comment: On the loop, What I wanted to do is the DB_TaskImages.get where I pass it the ID/Key for each array element of the insertedImages array.  I wasn't quite sure how to set up the promise chain.  I was looking at setting another array with the ID's from insertImages and passing that to Promise.All, and do the DB_TaskImages inside of that.

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell what the solution is from the 10 lines of code you posted

Answer (score 0):

You can use `db.allDocs({keys: …})` to fetch multiple documents at once. Depending on your use case and document structure, it might be even easier to create a small view that emits just the documents with attachments.

Below I have used db.allDocs. I have rewritten your code in a bit more functional style, which might simplify the code.

```
 DB_WorkIssues.allDocs({ include_docs: true, descending: false }).then(function (response) {

    // We only need the `doc` property from each row, so we map the docs functionally.
    var docs = response.rows.map(function (row) { return row.doc; });
    // Filter to docs with images.
    var docsWithImages = docs.filter(function (doc) { return doc.IsAttachmentInserted; });

    if (docsWithImages.length) {
      // I don't know what this does, so I left it here. Side effect?
      CTL_HiddenJsonWorkIssues.val(JSON.stringify(updated));

      // Depending on how many documents you have and how large they are,
      // it might be a good strategy to fetch the images in multiple batches.
      // Then you should use Promise.all().
      var keys = docsWithImages.map(function(doc) { return doc._id; });
      return DB_TaskImages.allDocs({ keys: keys, include_docs: true, attachments: true });
    }

    // Return an empty response if there are no images.
    return {};
 }).then(function (imagesResponse) {
   var attachmentObjects = imagesResponse.rows
     // Map the rows to the documents.
     .map(function(row) { return row.doc; })
     // Make sure there are only documents with attachments. This shouldn't be necessary if the flag `IsAttachmentInserted` is always consistent with the _attachments property, but let's make extra sure.
      .filter(function (doc) { return !!doc._attachments; })
      .map(function (doc) { return doc._attachments });

    // Extract the attachments as array. I'd say that another structure would be easier to read and process, but as your function ends there, I can't say for sure.
    var attachments = attachmentObjects.reduce(function (list, attachmentObject) {
      for (var key in attachmentObject) {
        list.push([key, attachmentObject[key]);
      }
      return list;
    }, []);
    return attachments;
  }).then(function () {
  …
```

Just for fun, this is the ES2016 version, which is less verbose:

```
 DB_WorkIssues.allDocs({ include_docs: true, descending: false }).then(({rows}) => {
   const docsWithImages = rows
     .map(({doc}) => doc)
     .filter(({IsAttachmentInserted}) => IsAttachmentInserted);

   if (docsWithImages.length) {
     CTL_HiddenJsonWorkIssues.val(JSON.stringify(updated));
     return DB_TaskImages.allDocs({ keys: docsWithImages.map(({_id}) => _id), include_docs: true, attachments: true });
    }
    return {};
 }).then(({rows}) =>
   rows.map(({doc: {_attachments}) => _attachments)
   .filter(att => att)
   .reduce((list, attachmentObject) => {
     for (var key in attachmentObject) {
       list.push([key, attachmentObject[key]);
     }
     return list;
   }, [])
  }).then(function () {
  …
```

Comment: That works great.  I have a better understanding from these examples.  Two questions: 1. you use a const for the keys to use in the alldocs call. Any reason why you used that over a var?  2. How would you set up the call to a Promise.all using the keys array?  Thanks,

Comment: Also you mentioned the JSON.stringify.  This is an MVC app and I need to get the data back from javascript to c# which is done by a string.  So I send back a json string to the C# app to then take the images and move them to the server.

Comment: One last thing.  When you reduce the imagesResponse down to the attachments array, it works great.  Except that you lose the original value of the attachment record that is only in the imagesResponse. Is there an easy way to add that to technique you did?  I can do it by manually creating an array using the imagesResponse without the reduction but if there is a better way, I would like to use that.  Thanks.

Comment: On that last point: Array methods `.filter()` and `.map()` are algebraically commutative with respect to each other (with the practical proviso that the filter doesn't rely on data provided by the map). In this case the two methods are truly commutative (the proviso is met) and `var docs = response.rows.map(...); var docsWithImages = docs.filter(...);` can be written `var rowsWithImages = response.rows.filter(...); var docsWithImages = rowsWithImages.map(...);`. If I'm right, the mystery "side-effects" line would be `CTL_HiddenJsonWorkIssues.val(JSON.stringify(rowsWithImages))`.

Comment: BTW, that same commutativity can be exploited further down when processing `imagesResponse.rows`. The `.map(...).filter(...).map(...)` chain can be rearranged as `.filter(...).map(...).map(...)` and the two adjacent maps combined to give `.filter(...).map(...)`.

Comment: @tshad the `const` was a typo. I'm using ES2016+ and avoid var in favor of const and let. In that ES5 example this should be a var, though. I edited my answer.

And I'm sorry, but I can't follow your last point. I can't see what you mean with "the original value if the attachment record". Can you post some real-life documents and an example of what you want to get at the end? I think I can improve my code easily then.

And @Roamer-1888: correct, thanks! It would make much more sense to filter first, and the multiple map functions are unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I think there's even more potential for optimization: The flag 'IsAttachmentInserted' is probably not necessary. When a document has an _attachments property, this should be enough. You would have to handle several edge cases: What if IsAttachmentInserted is true, but there are no attachments? What if IsAttachmentInserted is false, but there are attachments? I personally would create a small map/reduce view in PouchDB that emits one row per _attachment key. You get consistent data and local caching for free with that. Even better: use CouchDB on the server.